# How to correctly import AACDecoder android library to Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, aac

I'm trying to import `AACDecoder-Android library` (https://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/) into my Android Studio but I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load aacdecoder: findLibrary returned null
```

I've read a few questions related to this issue here on SO but none have worked. This is the file directory structure that I currently have:

### [image: File structure]

And I've added the following to my `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile files('libs/libaacdecoder.jar')
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing this error while trying to import the library or while trying to run the app?

Comment: When trying to run the app. The actual build in Android Studio is not giving any errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me. Copy the "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "mips" and "x86" folders into src/main/jniLibs (create this folder if it's not there). Clean the project and run it. I hope it helps.